# kotlin does wrong equations. it does not calculate correctly

Tags: java, kotlin, math, area, triangle

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val pie = 22/7
    println("Enter a number for triangle area")
    val input = readLine()?: ""
    val a = input.toInt() * input.toInt()  * pie
    println(a)
}
```

here when I input 6 it should give us 113.142857143 or 113.14

Instead, it gives 108

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEHeC.png)

and with javascript it's fine

[js output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FgdT.png)

Comment: Looks like it's using integer arithmetic.  `(int)(22/7)` is `3` and `3*6*6` is `108`.

Comment: Try printing out pie.

Comment: Kotlin is just respecting the law: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~alopez-o/math-faq/mathtext/node18.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It treats the pie as an integer. After rounding the pie will become 3, so 6 * 3 * 3 is 108.

There are numbers of ways to solve this but I recommend using BigDecimal to calculate decimals.

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val pie = BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.PI) // Either Math.PI or 22/7, one is 3.1415 another is 3.1428
    println("Enter a number for triangle area")
    val input = readLine()?: "0" // PLEASE DO INPUT VALIDATION HERE
    val inputDecimal = BigDecimal(input)
    val a = inputDecimal.multiply(inputDecimal).multiply(pie)
    println(a)
}
```